# How to control submit url action in Wicket form?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket web application with Page mounted to bookmarkable alias. The page contains a form object with submit action.

The problem is that though the form belongs to the page the action url doesn't contain page alias, but rather created in cryptic form of wicket action. 
Is there a way to adjust that behavior, so link will be like *page_alias/submit* ?

```
...
setRenderStrategy(IRequestCycleSettings.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
mountBookmarkablePage("/resetpwd", ResetPasswordPage.class); 
...
public ResetPasswordPage(final String id, final PageParameters parameters) {
    final Form form = new StatelessForm();
    form.add(new Button("submit") { 
     public void onSubmit() {
         ...
        });
 add(form);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you subclass [`StatelessForm`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/StatelessForm.html) instead of [`Form`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.html), this will take you part of the way. Rather than having something like

> action="myapp/?wicket:interface=:1:eventEditor::IFormSubmitListener::"

with the page containing the form mounted at a bookmarkable URL, you'll get something like, for example,

> action="myapp/mount/path/some/params/?wicket:interface=:0:eventEditor::IFormSubmitListener::"

This uses a [`MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/MixedParamHybridUrlCodingStrategy.html) for the mount in `WebApplication.init()`

You can then override `encodeUrlInHiddenFields()` to return `true`, which will give you a clean URL in the `action` attribute.

However, all this doesn't really change the way Wicket works with forms, i. e., you still have some Wicket-specific state data in the client's markup. The reason why this is so hard, I believe, is that Wicket is meant to help you build a web app that *has* state. I noticed that Wicket does a lot of stuff (like comparing submitted form values with what the model's getters return before the setters are called) behind the scenes, that I know too little about to be comfortable when just cutting it out.

You can use Wicket to provide RESTful web services, though, as outlined in [this blog post](http://blog.brunoborges.com.br/2008/11/restful-web-services-with-wicket.html). There's also a [project on Google code called wicket-rest](http://code.google.com/p/wicket-rest/) that expands on this idea. Note that this seems to work as simple as it does because it just never uses the whole component based UI building stuff.

The guy who wrote [this post](http://wiki.donohoedigital.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Bookmarkable%20Form%20Submission%20in%20Wicket) had a different problem, but it helped me understand Wicket forms a little better anyway.

Comment: I tried this solution, but if I override encodeUrlInHiddenFields(), Wicket doesn't actually call my onSubmit() method when the form button is clicked. If I comment that method back out again, the form works fine. Something about a combination of encoreUrlInHiddenFields() and StatelessForm just doesn't seem to work (perhaps they're just not compatible.)

Comment: @Trejkaz Based on some debugging I did, the request handlers are different thanks to logic inside `AbstractBookmarkableMapper#mapRequest` and the reason seems to go back to the page mounting. Some logic might need to change in the mounting class to fully allow the override like this.

Answer (score 1):

you can hide a lot of the request mumbo jumbo by using a HybridUrlCodingStrategy like so:

```
mount(new HybridUrlCodingStrategy("/resetpwd", ResetPasswordPage.class));
```

Then when the click submit, assuming you don't redirect to a new page, the url would change from

*mysite.com/DocRoot/resetpwd*

to

*mysite.com/DocRoot/resetpwd.1*

or if you really want it to be *mysite.com/DocRoot/resetpwd/submit* you could create a new bookmarkable page, say ResetPasswordResult.class, set your response page to that and mount it at "/resetpwd/submit"

You might look at other encoding strategies to see if their is another that suits you better:
http://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/url-coding-strategies.html

Comment: This is slightly beside the point, I think. The `action` of the form will by default not use the pretty url of its surrounding page at all, but just some Wicket parameters to retrieve the serialized form instance and call its `onSubmit` handler, although that might then redirect to a pretty URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://day-to-day-stuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/wicket-extreme-consistent-urls.html and try to adapt that for Forms.